# .exe has stopped working using VS C compiler

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008

I spent a long time searching for an answer to this, but I haven't found anything that fixes my problem. I'm fairly new to C.

The code reads through two massive catalogs and compares values between them, then writes various results to multiple data files. It's taking between 5 minutes to 2 hours to run, depending on the catalogs.

This issue is this: the program stops running right before it gets to the end. I get the message "filename.exe has stopped working". I don't think it's a scanf assignment issue, since all my variables are strings. I compile using the -Wall option and it compiles fine and the only warnings I get are "use fopen_s" or "use fscanf_s", which I hear is not really important. When I check the output files, they are 1-3 lines shorter than they should be, and stop halfway through a line. I think it might have something to do with the EOF on my while loops, but really I've been messing with this for a long time and I can't figure it out.

This is not my code, but rather code someone else has sent me that I've had to re-purpose. I'm using the VS Studio Command prompt to compile. I edit the file in notepad++.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#define  ANG_DIST_LIMIT  100  /* arcsecond */ 

void main(void)

{

 FILE  *in1, *in2, *out1, *out2, *out_str, *out_str_mul, *out_non, *out_non_1 ;
  char   cid1[20], cx[18], cy[18], cz[18], cmag[5], cra[12], cde[12], 
         cpmr[12], cpmd[12], cpu[12], cme[6], ccolor[2], cid2[4], 
         cid0_[7], cid_[9], cra_[13], cde_[13], cmg_[6], cmf_[3] ;

  int    lrs_id, id_l, id_ist_n, id_gla_n, mfg_n, star_cnt  ;

  double ra_l, dec_l, mag_l, ra_n, dec_n, mag_n, mag_err,
         ra_diff, de_diff, de_sum, ang_dist, PI;



  in1 = fopen("filepath1.txt", "r") ;
  in2 = fopen("filepath2.cat", "r") ;

  out1 = fopen("filepath3.dat", "w") ;
  out2 = fopen("filepath4.dat", "w") ;
  out_str = fopen("filepath5.dat", "w") ;
  out_str_mul = fopen("filepath6.dat", "w") ;
  out_non = fopen("filepath7.dat", "w") ;
  out_non_1 = fopen("filepath8.dat", "w") ;
  PI = 3.141592653589 ;
  lrs_id = 0 ;


  // Read from first catalog until end of file
  while (fscanf(in1, "%s", cid1) != EOF)  
     {
     fscanf(in1, "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s",
           cx, cy, cz, cmag, cra, cde, cpmr, cpmd, cpu, cme, ccolor, cid2) ;
     lrs_id++ ;
     id_l = atoi(cid2) ;
     ra_l = atof(cra) ;
     dec_l = atof(cde) ;
     mag_l = atof(cmag) ;
     mag_err = atof(cme) ;

     star_cnt = 0 ;
    // For each item in catalog 1, find an item in catalog 2 that matches
     while ( fscanf(in2, "%s", cid0_) != EOF) 
        {
        fscanf(in2, "%s %s %s %s %s", cid_,  cra_, cde_, cmg_, cmf_) ;
        id_ist_n = atoi(cid0_) ;
        id_gla_n = atoi(cid_) ;
        ra_n  = atof(cra_) ;
        dec_n = atof(cde_) ;
        mag_n = atof(cmg_) ;
        mfg_n = atoi(cmf_) ;

        ra_diff = (ra_l - ra_n)/180.*PI ;
        de_diff = (dec_l - dec_n)/180.*PI ; 
        de_sum  = (dec_l + dec_n)/180.*PI ;
        ang_dist = sqrt(de_diff*de_diff +cos(de_sum/2.)*ra_diff*ra_diff)*180./PI ; 

        if (ang_dist < 1.0)
           fprintf(out1, "%5d %10.3f %12.8f %12.8f %12.8f %12.8f %5d\n", 
            lrs_id, ang_dist*3600.0, ra_l, dec_l, ra_n, dec_n, id_ist_n) ;
        if (ang_dist*3600.0 < ANG_DIST_LIMIT)
           {
           star_cnt++ ; 
           fprintf(out2, "%5d %8.3f %12.8f %12.8f %12.8f %12.8f %5d\n", 
            lrs_id, ang_dist*3600.0, ra_l, dec_l, ra_n, dec_n, id_ist_n) ;
           }
        } 

     if (star_cnt > 0) 
        {
        fprintf(out_str, "%4d %3d     %8.3f %8.3f %6.2f\n", 
             lrs_id, star_cnt, ra_l, dec_l, mag_l) ;
        if (star_cnt > 1) 
           fprintf(out_str_mul, "%4d %3d     %8.3f %8.3f %6.2f\n", 
            lrs_id, star_cnt, ra_l, dec_l, mag_l) ;
        }
     else 
        {
        fprintf(out_non, "%4d %3d     %8.3f %8.3f %6.2f\n", 
                 lrs_id, star_cnt, ra_l, dec_l, mag_l) ;
        fprintf(out_non_1, "%19s  %20.15f    %20.15f    %20.15f   %8.2f  %12.8f    %14.8f %14.8f %14.8f   %15.6f %7.4f %2d  %8d\n", 
       cid1, atof(cx), atof(cy), atof(cz), mag_l, ra_l, dec_l, atof(cpmr), atof(cpmd), atof(cpu), atof(cme), atoi(ccolor), id_l) ;
        }
     rewind (in2) ;
     } 

}
```

There are a lot of variables that I don't use, due to the nature of the code.

I apologize if there's a glaring issue I'm not getting. I've done what I can and any help would really be appreciated. I'll provide any details I've left out.

Comment: Run it with the debugger to find out where exactly the problem happens.

Comment: If that was the code you inherited, you're probably better off throwing it all away and writing it properly from scratch.

Comment: Most likely: you don't check if `fopen` returns `NULL`, which it will if the file cannot be opened for some reason (for ex. because the file does not exist).

Comment: In a conforming C program, the return type of `main()` is `int`, never `void`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger you should tell him that main returning void is most likely not the problem here.

Comment: This code is *ridiculously* bad. Make a specification for the required functionality and do a full rewrite. Do it competently and it'll run in under a minute while written in Python.

Comment: @MichaelWalz, of course `fscanf()` returns `EOF` at the end of the file, and in a few other circumstances as well.  See section [7.21.6.2/16](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p16) of the standard.  If the stream is at end-of-file, attempting to read from it produces an input failure, which causes EOF to be returned, except in the case of a partial read.

Comment: @MichaelWalz The files definitely open, since the code uses the files to write to the output files. It almost finishes running, but stops just short.

Also, I haven't figured out how to run a debugger with my computer, I've been having separate issues with that.

Comment: And I know the code is bad, but that's kinda what I inherited. I am new to C though, so what specifically is bad about it?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks, I wasn't sure which type to put.

Comment: @EOF, I don't think it'll be able to do it under a minute. The catalogs I'm accessing are 118,000 lines and 300,000 lines each, with 500 bytes per line. But yeah, I'm sure there's a faster way.

Comment: @user3735221: All of the code in `main()` instead of in reasonable functions, bad variable naming, all variables declared at outermost block scope, **no error checking whatsoever**, comparing two files by iterating over the second file for every line in the first file. There's more, but this alone would do it.

Comment: @user3735221, I wouldn't be surprised if it did run in under a minute if written properly.  Your data are not huge, but you perform a great deal more I/O than you need to do, and I/O is very expensive.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I suspect the algorithm would be bad even *without* I/O. If a specification was given, it could probably be made orders of magnitude faster by e.g. sorting the inputs.

Comment: @EOF Thanks for the input. The code is so close to working that I just want to finish it to get the results. And there are 10 other C codes written in a similar manner that I would have to all re-write in python (which I'm not even that great at). I guess it's best to do it anyways though.

Comment: @EOF What do you mean exactly by specification?

Comment: @user3735221: What is the program *supposed to do*?

Comment: @JohnBollinger sorry of course, comment deleted, you can delete yours, thanks.

Comment: @EOF I changed the files names, they give some specification. I'm not sure how I could sort the inputs any more than they already are.

Comment: @EOF, I agree that a specification might help, but I'm doubtful that there is a suitable sort order.  The code appears to be matching points based on distance on the surface of a sphere, or an equivalent.  That doesn't afford a good 1D sort order, though one could probably do at least a bit better than comparing every single pair.

Comment: @EOF what do you mean by variables being declared at outermost block scope?

Comment: @JohnBollinger You are correct, it matches two catalogs of stars to find the same star in each catalog. Do you have suggestions that might be better than a nested while loop? Split the catalogs based on general area and then compare? That's actually a good idea, thanks!

Comment: For example, `ra_n` is *declared* at the beginning of `main()`, but it is only *used* inside the innermost `while()`. It should also be *declared* in the innermost `while()`.

Comment: Are the catalogs huge ? 1000s of entries, millions ? You might consider reading them all into memory nowadays.

Comment: I appreciate the help, guys. Still don't know what's causing the initial error, but it seems like if I do a re-write and make it actually good, the issue might sort itself out.

Comment: @EOF Oh yeah of course, thanks. Not exactly sure why he did it like that. This code was made over 10 years ago so who knows :/

Comment: The Visual Studio debugger normally runs just fine. Pressing F5 in VS lauches your program with the debugger. Doesn't that work for you ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz I'm only using the Visual Studio command line to run code that I make in Notepad++. I have no idea how to build a solution in VS itself. Even when I do "hello world" there are some stupid issues that I just don't want to bother with. The configuration of the computer is secure as well, which causes additional issues. If you think it's necessary i might give it another shot.

Comment: Each `char` array size seems to be tailored to its use. For this fault finding purpose, define all of the `cid1[20]` etc. arrays as `cid1[100]` etc. Never be too tight with your array sizes unless really necessary - just one overrun array renders the code useless.

Comment: @WeatherVane I thought about that, but the catalogs are in a very specific format, so I don't think that's the issue. I'll try it though and see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: In VS: File-New-Project, then chose Templates->Visual C++->Win32->Win32 Console Application. The rest is pretty obvious.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yeah I ran it again with larger sizes and it's still messed up.